# C++ InputReader - file could not be opened

Tags: c++

I have a code that I got it from some resources, when I run the code its keep giving me an error "file could not be opened", and i am not familiar with C++ can you help me to analyse this issue?

I tried to add the file path in fin.open(filename); but did not work
ERROR: "file could not be opened"

to run the code

1. Keep project files in one folder.
2. use the CMD to build clustering.exe.

   "g++ -std=c++11 clustering.cpp -o clustering.exe"
3. Run using the following command.

   "./clustering.exe [intput.txt] [n] [eps] [minPts]"

the full code :

```
class DBSCAN {
public:
int n, minPts;
double eps;
vector<Point> points;
int size;
vector<vector<int> > adjPoints;
vector<bool> visited;
vector<vector<int> > cluster;
int clusterIdx;

DBSCAN(int n, double eps, int minPts, vector<Point> points) {
    this->n = n;
    this->eps = eps;
    this->minPts = minPts;
    this->points = points;
    this->size = (int)points.size();
    adjPoints.resize(size);
    this->clusterIdx=-1;
}
void run () {
    checkNearPoints();
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(points[i].cluster != NOT_CLASSIFIED) continue;
        
        if(isCoreObject(i)) {
            dfs(i, ++clusterIdx);
        } else {
            points[i].cluster = NOISE;
        }
    }
    
    cluster.resize(clusterIdx+1);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(points[i].cluster != NOISE) {
            cluster[points[i].cluster].push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

void dfs (int now, int c) {
    points[now].cluster = c;
    if(!isCoreObject(now)) return;
    
    for(auto&next:adjPoints[now]) {
        if(points[next].cluster != NOT_CLASSIFIED) continue;
        dfs(next, c);
    }
}

void checkNearPoints() {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++) {
            if(i==j) continue;
            if(points[i].getDis(points[j]) <= eps) {
                points[i].ptsCnt++;
                adjPoints[i].push_back(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
// is idx'th point core object?
bool isCoreObject(int idx) {
    return points[idx].ptsCnt >= minPts;
}

vector<vector<int> > getCluster() {
    return cluster;
}};
```

and then I use the InputReader class

```
class InputReader { 
        private:
        ifstream fin;
        vector<Point> points; 

        public:
        InputReader(string filename) {
            fin.open(filename);
        
            if (!fin) {
                cout << filename << " file could not be opened\n";
                exit(0);
            }
        
            parse();
        }

        void parse() {
            int idx;
            double x, y;

            while (!fin.eof()) {
                fin >> idx >> x >> y;
                points.push_back({x, y, 0, NOT_CLASSIFIED});
            }

            points.pop_back();
        }

        vector<Point> getPoints() {
            return points;
        }
    };
```

after that, there is an output class

```
    class OutputPrinter {
private:
    ofstream fout;
    vector<vector<int> > cluster;
    string filename;
    int n;
public:
    OutputPrinter(int n, string filename, vector<vector<int> > cluster) {
        this->n = n;
        this->cluster = cluster;
        
        // remove ".txt" from filename
        if(filename.size()<4){
            cout << filename << "input file name's format is wrong\n";
            exit(0);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) filename.pop_back();
        this->filename = filename;
        
        // sort by size decending order
        sort(cluster.begin(), cluster.end(), [&](const vector<int> i, const vector<int> j) {
            return (int)i.size() > (int)j.size();
        });
    }
    void print() {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            fout.open(filename+"_cluster_"+to_string(i)+".txt");
            
            for(int j=0;j<cluster[i].size();j++) {
                fout << cluster[i][j] << endl;
            }
            
            fout.close();
        }
    }
};
```

and in the end the main class

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if(argc!=5) {
        cout << "Please follow this format. clustering.exe [input] [n] [eps] [minPts]";
        return 0;
    }
    
    string inputFileName(argv[4]);
    string n(argv[2]);
    string eps(argv[3]);
    string minPts(argv[4]);
    
    InputReader inputReader(inputFileName);
    
    DBSCAN dbScan(stoi(n), stod(eps), stoi(minPts), inputReader.getPoints());
    dbScan.run();
    
    OutputPrinter outputPrinter(stoi(n), inputFileName, dbScan.getCluster());
    outputPrinter.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of code to wade through here to solve what should be a simple problem.  please post a [mre].

Comment: The program reads input file name from `argv[4]` - the fourth command line argument. Strangely, `minPts` is read from the same argument. Nothing at all touches the first. Looks like a typo to me; `string inputFileName(argv[4]);` was probably meant to be `string inputFileName(argv[1]);` Also, I don't believe you are meant to literally enclose actual command-line arguments in square brackets. I imagine your file is named `intput.txt` and not `[intput.txt]`